# Two onclick events in a single href line of code

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a php JavaScript `onclick` event -

```
<td height="132" colspan="2"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="pkgsPopup('<?='http://'.$hLnk?>');" rel="nofollow"> <img alt="<?=$row['Hotel_Text']?>"  title="<?=$row['Hotel_Text']?>" src="<?=$iPth?>hotels/<?=$hImg?>.jpg" width="195" height="115" /> </a>
```

I would like to add a second `onclick` event with an `if/else` statement to this line -

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="pkgsPopup('<?='http://'.$hLnk?>');
```

Comment: Why would you need two `onClick` events? And what is the if/else going to do?

Comment: This is a JAVASCRIPT client-side question. PHP has nothing to do with it so please show your HTML OUTPUT, not your PHP code.

Comment: It works alright with one onclick event as it display a popup that has been pre-defined in php eg <?=$iPth?> but I want to make an offer so the If statement will be if it contains this parameter, display this pop up else display the other pop up

Answer (score 0):

You can have that **if condition** in JavaScript, within your *onClick* handler.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="if(condition){doSomething();}"></a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**Echo out** the relevant parts in PHP.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLD79/)**

Answer (score 0):

Why not add your if/else statement to the existing onclick handler:

```
onclick="pkgsPopup('<?= 'http://' .$hLnk?>');if (x) doSomething(); else doSomethingElse();"
```

Update, here's a cleaner way:

```
<?php
    $onclick = 'onclick="';
    if (strpos($hImg, 'rom') == 0) $onclick .= "romPopup('http://$dealPth');";
    else $onclick .= "pkgsPopup('http://$hLnk');";
    $onclick .= '"';
?>

<a href="javascript:;" <?= $onclick ?> rel="nofollow"> <img alt="<?=$row['Hotel_Text']?>" title="<?=$row['Hotel_Text']?>" src="<?=$iPth?>hotels/<?=$hImg?>.jpg" width="195" height="115" /> </a>
```

Comment: I tried this   <a href="javascript:;"if ( '$hImg' LIKE "rom%%") { onclick="romPopup('<?='http://'.$dealPth?>');"} else { onclick="pkgsPopup('<?='http://'.$hLnk?>');"} rel="nofollow"> <img alt="<?=$row['Hotel_Text']?>"  title="<?=$row['Hotel_Text']?>" src="<?=$iPth?>hotels/<?=$hImg?>.jpg" width="195" height="115" /> </a>   It pops up but display a 404 page even when the page exists

Comment: I think you might be mixing different languages.  Like isn't a function you can use in in JavaScript or PHP.  Since you're trying to use $hImg, you'll need to wrap that inside of <?php ?> tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript">
 function handleClick(){
   if(something == somethingElse){
     // do the conditional stuff
   }
   pkgsPopup('<?='http://'.$hLnk?>');
 }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="handleClick();">...</a>
```

As you can see, you can handle it with one event. You can even use PHP to generate different javascript on different situations.